# JQuery not working in new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I work with JSF and spring boot. I have jquery script in my xhtml file that dynamically adds on click method to component that appears. Everything is working but when I copy link and open a new tab with this link. In new tab my JQuery script is run. On click is not working there. What do I wrong?

```
 <script>
                $('#menu\\:notification, #menu\\:notificationGrowlMessageError_container')
                .on('click', showUserTaskListIfNotificationForUser);
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap it with `$(document).ready();` like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#menu\\:notification, #menu\\:notificationGrowlMessageError_container')
                .on('click', showUserTaskListIfNotificationForUser);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Will it be working when  ids: '#menu\\:notification, #menu\\:notificationGrowlMessageError_container' are dynamically added? After document is ready

Comment: Now it's working. Why is that? Why in first page it is working, but in new tab not? Why I need ready? I will accept your answer after explaining.

Comment: It's because the first page was already in the DOM when the script ran, but the second probably not. So you have to use `ready()`that makes sure the DOM was completely loaded and then you run your Javascript, which will see now all the HTML elements.

Comment: Thanks. Now I see. It was strange for me that the first had Dom already loaded. I thought for the second it would be the same.